# What is // in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

What is `//` in XSLT? (e.g. `$currentPage//node`)

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete, detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what // in xslt? e.g.
>   ($currentPage//node)

In XPath the abbreviation:

> [**`//` is short for
>   `/descendant-or-self::node()/`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)

The value of some attributes of xslt instructions (such as the `select` attribute) must be an XPath expression.

Therefore,

```
($currentPage//node)
```

stands for

```
($currentPage/descendant-or-self::node()/node)
```

This selects all elements named `node` that are children of nodes that are either contained in the variable `$currentPage` or are descendents of nodes that are contained in the variable `$currentPage`.

**Do note** that in the provided expression `node()` is a *node-test* (it selects all node types on the `descendant-or-self::` axis, such as elements, text nodes, comments and processing-instructions.

On the other side, `somePath/node` is a shorthand for `somePath/child::node` and only selects elements named `node` that are children of the context node.

I strongly recommend not to use the name `node` for an element in order to avoid this confusion.

Comment: @Dimitre - I'm nitpicking on what is otherwise a good answer, but the penultimate paragraph's incorrect. They won't be children of the context node, they'll be children of the nodes selected by 'somePath'

Comment: @Alohci: Yes and the "context node" at any moment is the node, from which the next location-step is performed -- this means that  `child::node` is determined in `somePath/child::node`, the context node is any node that is selected by `somePath`. So, both you and I are saying the same thing :)

Comment: `node()/node` is confusing. `node()` is a predefined function, and `node` is a placeholder variable? `node()/foo` would be less confusing.

Comment: @Joren: `node()` it's not a function but a [node test](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-kind-test) like `comment()`, `text()`, `processing-instruction()` in XPath 1.0 and `element()`, `attribute()` and `document-node()` in XPath 2.0

Comment: @Joren: Yes, it clearly is confusing and a source for frequent errors. One should know this and never use names like "node" or "element" or "attribute" or "text" or "processing-instruction" or "namespace" for element names. Do note that it is the OP that is using "node" as an element name -- not I... :)

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Correct answer by the way.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like it's part of **[XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)**, which can be used within XSLT to search the tree for given nodes matching a path.  It's a similar technology to CSS selectors.

The **double slash** does a descendant search at any depth.

For example:

```
elementa//elementb
```

would match any elementb element which is a descendent of an elementa element, even if there are other levels in between, eg:

```
<elementa>
  <someelement>
    <elementb>
    </elementb>
  </someelement>
</elementa>
```